# Is there a way to get rid of that sulfur-y, fart-bomb-like smell form cooking daikon?

Tags: vegetables, soup, chinese-cuisine

Made a chinese-style daikon soup in a pressure cooker, and it left an sulfury odor reminiscent to a subtle fart bomb. I know veges and roots that have sulfuric compounds tend to do this. Is there a way to prep the daikon to prevent this from happening?

Perhaps, an acid wash or quick pickling or a rinse in baking soda?

Comment: A way to address the sulfuric "bite" of raw onions is to slice them thin and then soak them in a baking soda solution for 10-15 minutes. You can try to do the same with sliced daikon, but know that even if it works, doing so is going to affect the flavor and won't get rid of the smell entirely.

Comment: Thank you, Abion47. Good points. :)